# BIOS Menu shows Ubuntu but Disk Management doesn't

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a 1 TB HDD system. I had installed Ubuntu 18.04 in a dual boot with Windows 10. It was my first ever time installing as OS besides Windows, so I did some stuff which apparently I shouldn't have.

I had made a 40 GB partition for Ubuntu through Windows Disk Management.
While installing Ubuntu, I was allocating space for root, home and swap. I didn't know how much to give for root, so I just gave like 8 GB to root and turns out it was a big mistake. Within one day of usage I started getting low on space.
So I tried to uninstall Ubuntu.

I went into Windows Disk Management to delete the Ubuntu partition but it didn't show any such partition. But when I rebooted, it opened in grub. So I went back to windows, removed grub through cmd and booted into BIOS to check if Ubuntu was still there, and it was.

So basically now, if I check windows disk management, it shows no Ubuntu disk

[image]

but if I go to bios, I still get an option to boot into Ubuntu.

[image]

How is this possible, and how do I solve this?

Comment: What you are seeing in your BIOS is probably just the old EFI entries for Ubuntu on the EFI partition. If you boot your Ubuntu install media and go to a live session (“Try Ubuntu” option) you can probably mount the EFI partition and delete the Ubuntu folder. If you ever want to install Ubuntu again I recommend finding an up to date guide on here and follow it carefully. There is a learning curve with Linux but in my opinion it’s far better than Windows. My laptop runs far better without all the Windows bloat that I cannot control

Comment: hey thankss so i deleted those entires
and now if i go to BIOS it only shows Windows so i think you were right
although disk management still shows like an unnamed 266MB UEFI partition
any idea what that is?

Comment: I’ve just had a look at my laptop drive from Windows disk management and from GParted. From Windows it looks just like yours. It has no name. From GParted it has “EFI system partition” in the name column. I’ve no doubt it is what it says it is from GParted and you should not alter it any more. The EFI partition is vital for the boot process on a UEFI system.

Comment: Alright great thanks a lot! Do you think its safe for me now to install ubuntu again? If so, which drive do you suggest i shrink to create space from (since my friends said C is not a good option as it has windows on it), and also how much total space should i free up and how much of that should i give to root (i had to uninstall because of this exact thing where i made a mistake the last time)?

Comment: Sounds like there is nothing to stop you installing Ubuntu again. I suggest you follow this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Installing_Ubuntu_in_UEFI_mode It’s hard to advise you about where to take the space from without knowing which of your 3 partitions is likely to grow the fastest. You could just let the installer do it’s thing by choosing the “install alongside” option. Then if you later have space issues it’s easy to use Windows Disk Management and GParted to reallocate. Just make sure you boot the installer in UEFI mode. Good luck!